# How to get locations from string using spacy?

Tags: python, spacy

I want to take a string and see if it contains any named locations, as this is for a project that will involve many towns in england, it is important that it can recongise town names.

```
    import spacy

# Load the spaCy model for English
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Define the example string
example_string = "show me all the 5k races in burnley, london and in manchester or lancashire on october 2020"

# Process the input string with spaCy
doc = nlp(example_string)

# Initialize a list to store location names
location_names = []

# Extract location-related words using spaCy's named entity recognition (NER)
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ in ["GPE", "LOC"]:
        location_names.append(ent.text)

print("Location names:", location_names)
```

Is there any reason that this only recongises London or are the others just nor big enough to be able to be recongised?

Comment: Have you tried the larger models (`en_core_web_md` and `en_core_web_lg`)? https://spacy.io/models/en

Comment: Just tried it, definitely works better. Just got problems recongising smallish towns.

Comment: @dexta  all the town names should start with capital letters `burnley, london and in manchester or lancashire` and month names as well `october`